# Model.objects.all() returns integers for ForeignKeys and choice fields - how to force it to return names instead?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to export a .csv file using djqscsv. I know [the module supports foreign keys](https://github.com/azavea/django-queryset-csv#foreign-keys), however half of my model is choices and foreignkeys and I really don't want to hardcode it like shown in the link.

It just takes the table from the database as-is. Is there a fancy way to create a dynamic query that checks the field types and returns appropriate, actual data instead of just the IDs?

edit because apparently this is too hard to visualise:

```
class Bonus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Contact(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    person = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    bonus_field = models.ForeignKey(Bonus)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
```

choices.py

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (1, ("Sent")),
    (2, ("Requested")),
    (3, ("In progress")),
)
```

Contact.objects.all() returns url, email, person and **ID of row in Bonus**. I want it to return the corresponding name, but I don't want to write

```
Contact.objects.values('url', 'email', 'person', 'bonus_field__name')
```

because the full model is too big for that and I don't want to hardcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to iterate through the fields, and pick out the ForeignKeys to handle specially:

```
from django.db import models

# Get field_name, is_foreign_key pairs from model meta
fields_foreign = [(
   field.name, 
   isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey)
) for field in Contact._meta.fields]

# Assume every related model has a 'name' field,
# if you want to get 'name' fields of these models, 
# construct the list of field names to pass to values():
# something like ['url', 'email', 'person', 'bonus_field__name']
value_fields = [
    f[0] if not f[1] else "{}__name".format(f[0])
    for f in fields_foreign
]

# Now get the values
Contact.objects.values(*value_fields)
```

If by 'actual data', you mean the string returned by `__str__`:

```
contacts = Contact.objects.all()
for contact in contacts:
    values = []
    for f in fields_foreign:
        value = getattr(contact, f[0])
        if f[1]: # Foreignkey, call str() on the model object
           value = str(value) # this calls __str__ in model
        values.append(value)
    print values
```

If you want better performance, better use select_related() for the related models when querying all Contact objects.

About choices, Django provides an convenient method get_field_display() for every field with choices. To use this in the value list, first you have to know which fields have choices set:

```
# Now we have tuples (field_name, is_field_foreign, field_has_choices)
fields_foreign_choices = [(
   field.name, 
   isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey),
   bool(field.choices)
) for field in Contact._meta.fields]

# We can use the magic get_field_display() method
contacts = Contact.objects.all()
for contact in contacts:
    values = []
    for f in fields_foreign_choices:
        value = getattr(contact, f[0])
        if f[1]: # Foreignkey, call str() on the model object
           value = str(value) # this calls __str__ in model
        elif f[2]: # The field has choices
           display_method = getattr(contact, "get_{}_display".format(f[0])
           value = display_method()
        values.append(value)
    print values
```

For other fields like Datetime fields, you can do the same: extract the meta, and convert accordingly.

Comment: Hey, thank you, that's great, exactly what I was looking for! What about choices though? Is iterating over the dictionary from Contact.objects.values(*value_fields) and replacing the values accordingly the only way?

Comment: @zephi You can use get_field_display() method. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved the problem:

The last piece of code from @NeoWang indeed works (after a slight modification to return list of dictionaries in the same form Model.objects.values() does), however it is of no use in my particular case, because the djqscsv module requires a queryset. What I've done instead is I'm using first bit of that code for ForeignKey fields, and for choices right before writing the CSV I simply replace choice field integer values with corresponding names from choices tuples. The hardcoded part is just for three fields, so I'll put an appropriate comment and just go with it I guess.

So here's how that looks like:

Custom manager in models.py

```
class ContactManager(models.Manager):

    def get_values(self):

        fields_foreign = [(
           field.name, 
           isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey)
        ) for field in Contact._meta.fields]

        value_fields = [
            f[0] if not f[1] else "{}__name".format(f[0])
            for f in fields_foreign
        ]

        return Contact.objects.values(*value_fields)
```

Modifications in djqscsv.py (sadly we have to incorporate modifications, so we're gonna have to use our modified version in the project):

in djqscsv.py

```
## import your choices.py!
## add this method (hardcoded, so modify accordingly) 
def replace_choice(record):

    for key in record:
        if key == 'status':
## very readable line incoming (might remove unicode call if you don't need it)
            record[key] = unicode([v[1] for i, v in enumerate(STATUS_CHOICES) if v[0] == record[key]][0], 'utf-8')           
    return record

## modify this forloop
for record in values_qs:
    fixed_record = replace_choice(record)
    record = _sanitize_unicode_record(field_serializer_map, fixed_record)
    writer.writerow(record)
```

The replace_choice() method is hardcoded for my model, however you get the idea. It's fairly easy to build a dynamic solution on the pieces of code provided above and in @NeoWang answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom manager for `Contact`, overwrite the `values()` function and make it handle the `ForeignKey` fields as you like.

Comment: Please give an example with the minimum amount of code for OP to understand what you mean.